# Python: Insert into a postGreSQL table using python by passing parameters

Tags: python, sql, insert, psycopg2

I have two lists:

```
columns = ['id','name','address']
data = ['1,'John','LA'','2,'Jessica','TX'']
```

I have a table schema with the same columns as above and I am unable to insert data into the table using psycopg2 connections when I pass the values and column names as parameters.

```
cursor_r.execute("insert into test %s values %s ",tuple(column_names),tuple(values)))
```

I get the error as

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'id'"
```

I really am unable to figure what I'm doing wrong and would really appreciate any kind of help. Thank you in advance for trying to help me out.
EDIT: I tried typing in this query:

```
cursor_r.execute("insert into test (%s) values (%s) ", ((x for x in column_names),(str(y).replace("(","").replace(")","") for y in values)))
```

It now gives me the error that it cannot adapt to a type 'generator'

EDIT 2: I'm now getting the error that 'generator' object doesn't support indexing. Someone help me out

Comment: `data = ['1,'John','LA'','2,'Jessica','TX'']` this list gives error use `data = ["1,'John','LA'","2,'Jessica','TX'"]`

Comment: @mahendrakamble I stored the data dynamically. So list will obviously store it with ' ' right? I don't know if I can change that

Comment: `(x for x in column_names)` this part creates generator object thats why it gives that error

Comment: did you change that data list as i said..

Comment: @mahendrakamble It is not a manual entry into that list is what I mean. I don't know how to change it honestly

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` needs columns and values in `()` so you need `INSERT INTO test (%s) VALUES (%s)`

see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: I did that but it gave another kind of error. So I thought I should remove them @furas

Comment: I'm sorry. There was never an error there. But right now my error is
`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'generator'`

Comment: something wrong with arguments - maybe you need list of tuples `[('1','John','LA'), ('2,'Jessica','TX')] ` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Or maybe you have to use strings instead of lists because one `%s` expect one string, not list of elements. And maybe you will need `executemany()` to insert many rows (but I don't know if it will work if you have one set in columns and two sets in values.)